# Add Multiple Data Entries from CSV to 1 String in Python

Tags: python, loops, csv, for-loop

I have the following data in a .csv file:

```
1,-100,phrase1
2,-100,phrase2
3,1,phrase3
4,-100,phrase4
5,1,phrase5
```

I'd like to add all of the "phrase*" into one string when -100 is found, separated by comma until the last entry. So far I have the following:

```
import csv

output = []

with open('test_file.csv') as test_file:
    csv_reader_object = csv.reader(test_file)
    for expression_id, expression_weight, expression_phrase in csv_reader_object:
        expression_weight = int(expression_weight)

        if expression_weight == -100:
            output.append(expression_phrase)
            print(output)
```

I was thinking I could loop through the list, find -100, add the expression_phrase to a list, then loop through the list and add all of the expression phrases to one large string. I'm looking for the following output:

> string = (phrase1,phrase2,phrase4)

Any help/tips are appreciated. My head's been spinning trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this compactly in python by filtering the rows and joining the results on the comma. Comparing `"-100"` as a string seems okay in this case although conversions may be needed in more complicated cases

```
import csv

with open('test_file.csv') as test_file:
    final = ",".join(row[2] for row in csv.reader(test_file) if row[1] == "-100")
print(final)
```

If you want to gather multiple strings you can convert this to a for loop.

```
import csv

with open('test_file.csv') as test_file:
    phrases_1 = []
    phrases_2 = []
    for row in csv.reader(test_file):
        if row[1] == "-100":
            phrases_1.append(row[2])
        if row[0] == "1":
            phrases_2.append(row[2])
    return ",".join(phrases_1), ",".join(phrases_2)
```

You could also just do the first option a second time. You'll spend more time parsing the csv, but I don't think there will be a great difference.

Comment: If I wanted to create another string of phrases where expression_weight = 1 does it make sense to replicate the final variable and just look for row[1] == 1?

Comment: Except that breaking it into a for loop makes sense, so that you don't parse the file twice. I'll update.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. The key thing I was missing was the string join() method - will need to take note of this for the future. You saved me a massive headache.